# Calling putback() on istream multiple times

Tags: c++, istream

Many sites describe the **istream::putback()** function that lets you "put back" a character into the input stream so you can read it again in a subsequent reading operation.

What's to stop me, however, from calling **putback()** multiple times in sequence over the same stream? Of course, you're supposed to check for errors after every operation in order to find out if it succeeded; and yet, I wonder: is there any guarantee that a particular type of stream supports putting back more than one character at a time?

I'm only guessing here, but I can imagine **istringstream** is able to put back as many characters as the length of the string within the stream; but I'm not so sure that it is the same for **ifstream**.

Is any of this true? How do I find out how many characters I can **putback()** into an **istream**?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to read multiple characters from a stream you may unget them using `unget()`:

```
std::vector<char>&read_top5(std::istream & stream, std::vector<char> & container) {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    char c;
    int i=4;
    container.clear();

    while (stream && stream.get(c)) {
        container.push_back(c);
        if (--i < 0) break;
        if (c == '\n') break;
    }

    for (int j=0;j<(int)container.size();j++) {
        //stream.putback(container[j]); // not working
        stream.unget(); // working properly
    }

    return container;
}
```

This function reads the first 5 characters from stream while they are still in stream after the function exits.